# Android: How to launch external activity in current activity's process?

Tags: android

My app is comprised of a set of reusable Activities that other apps can reuse. For various reasons, I would like my Activities to be launched in context of the invoking Activity's process, instead of always being launched in my Activity's process (default behavior on Android). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I achieve this?

Android does not support this, for security reasons (e.g., your code gets to delete that app's data, your code gets to exploit that app's permissions).

Comment: Does this mean that if I launch an activity from a package other than my own, it will always be launched in a new task?  Or is it possible to have multiple processes in the same task?

Comment: @Neil Traft: The latter. "To the user, it will seem as if the map viewer is part of the same application as your activity, even though it's defined in another application and runs in that application's process. Android maintains this user experience by keeping both activities in the same task." (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask)